# Empty div has different position than non-empty div

Tags: css

I have 3 divs. Two of them have some text inside and one is empty. Like to display them in line but this empty div is a little misalignment from other two?

```
           +--+
 +--+ +--+ |  |
 |A | |B | +--+  
 +--+ +--+
```

And here is my css for those 3 divs

```
.box1, .box2, .box3 {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

Comment: [CSS Vertical align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: top;`

```css
.box{
    border: 1px solid #999;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">A</div>
<div class="box">B</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: The static positioning and the default document flow is rarely the best approach to use for alignment or layout. You should consider using _flex_ or _grid_ for proper layouts, which gives you finer control over how elements are displayed and positioned.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen Indeed, and your comment is an answer better suited for another question